# No se puede cargar el Archivo del proyecto (Visual studio 2022) proyecto de angular

Tags: visual-studio, .net, tfs, visual-studio-2022

Hola no estoy pudiendo cargar una solucion en angular cuando actualize del 2019 al 2022
[image: este es el error que salta]

creo que es algo de las rutas, me fije y tengo esos archivos que no encuentra, a alguien le paso algo similar? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera, en la instalación del visual studio 2019 en la ruta del error me aparecia una carpeta "v16.0" que en la del visual studio 2022 no tenia , copie esa carpeta la lleve a la del visual studio 2022 y me tomo todas las rutas del proyecto.